# Running program that you just installed with rpm

Tags: centos, centos6, rpm

I've just downloaded pgadmin from :

http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg92

and I've installed it :

```
rpm -ivh pgdg-centos92-9.2-6.noarch.rpm
```

How do I open it? where can I find it or do I need some additional steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That rpm just contains the files for adding the postgresql 9.2 repo to CentOS. You will need to download and install the relevant package. A bit of digging suggests that the package you want is [pgadmin3_92](http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repoview/) so

```
yum install pgadmin3_92
```

will install the programs for you to run.

Comment: Thanks Iain I'm a newbie I guess I did see that page but didn't understand what should I go. Thanks for the tip